# C++ Custom Client Handler

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

Below is the code that accepts a client... I just added a bit to add it to a pool which is a `list<Client>`. `Client` is my own class that is defined by `(SOCKET, Char*)` socket and ip address. The `addclient2pool()` function just adds to the list. Then I iterate through the list and send data via the stored socket in `Client`.

```
while(true) { 
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &n, &len);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    addClient2Pool(Client(ListenSocket, inet_ntoa(n.sin_addr)));
}
```

The socket seems to have closed so I can't send messages... `10057`. I am pretty sure there's something fundamentally wrong with the way I am storing the socket into `Client` class but I am new to C++.

```
void messageHandler() {
    int iSend;
    char* charB = "hello!";
    while(true) { 
        for(ClientPool::iterator it = mainClientPool.begin(); it != mainClientPool.end(); ++it) {
            Client c = *it;
            SOCKET sock = c.getSocket(); 
            iSend = send(sock, charB, sizeof(charB),0);
            if (iSend == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            }
        }
        Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

I used `std::thread nameofthread(void)` and `nameofthread.join();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues with your code.

You are passing `ListenSocket` to `Client()` when you should be passing `ClientSocket` instead:

```
addClient2Pool(Client(ClientSocket, inet_ntoa(n.sin_addr)));
```

If you need to shut down the server for any reason, you should close any active client sockets first. In your example, if `accept()` fails, you are calling `closesocket(ListenSocket)` and `WSACleanup()` without clearing `mainClientPool` first (I assume your `~Client()` deconstructor calls `closesocket()` on the client socket):

```
mainClientPool.clear(); // <-- add this
closesocket(ListenSocket);
WSACleanup();
```

When looping through your list, you need to use a `Client&` reference when deferencing the iterator so you are not making temporary copies of your `Client` objects that invoke their destructors when they go out of scope (thus closing your client sockets):

```
Client &c = *it; // <-- add '&'
```

You are misusing `sizeof()`.  Since `charB` is a `char*` and not a `char[]`, you need to use `strlen()` instead:

```
iSend = send(sock, charB, strlen(charB), 0);
```

Lastly, when `send()` (or any other socket operation) fails, you should close the failed client socket and remove it from your list.  Which means changing your `for()` loop into a `while()` loop so you can modify the list while you are looping through it:

```
void messageHandler() {
    ...
    while(true) { 
        ...
        ClientPool::iterator it = mainClientPool.begin();
        while (it != mainClientPool.end()) {
            ...
            if (iSend == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                ...
                it = mainClientPool.erase(it);
            } else {
                ++it;
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```